# Using PayPal in As3 for flash builder 4.5

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3, paypal, flash-builder

I am a reasonable beginner as a programmer just doing it for fun on and off for the last 12 years, have currently been blown a way with Flash Catalyst and Flash builder and now am close to finishing my Master piece.

I have decided to use a little PayPal on my site to see if i could earn a little money and too incorporate it just so i know i can do it.

But when i signed up for paypal they gave me some HTML code for the PayPal Button, Which has left me a little confused can any one suggest away to incorporate HTML into my AS3 code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for trying people :)

But i found an answer more to my taste :)

```
function buynow (event:MouseEvent):void
{
      var url:String = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
      var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
      var paypal_buynow:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
      paypal_buynow.cmd="_s-xclick"; //<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
      paypal_buynow.hosted_button_id="123456778456"; //<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="123456778456">
      request.data = paypal_buynow;
      navigateToURL(request);
      trace(paypal_buynow)
}
```

Comment: you should mark your answer as correct, so that more people see it :)

Comment: I agree annonymously but the web site wouldn't let me for 24 hrs!

Answer (score 0):

1.
The only way I can think of straight off is to send a string with the html code in it to php, and handle the rest there.

2.
If you can put the html in the html file that contains the rest of the code for your website, I would definitely recommend doing that over using actionscript.

EDIT:

After reading your question again, I think I may have been answering you wrong.
You don't put html code in your actionscript. When you publish your swf and html files, or if you have already created a html file you need to put that code somewhere between the  and  tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PayPal, I bet you will have a website for your *masterpiece*. So here's what I would do:

I would create a button in my swf which tells people to donate if they liked the application. This button would simply direct their browser to the donate page of your website. The code you got from PayPal would go on that html / php / whatever page.

The code to make the button open the url:

```
function openDonationPage(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var ur:URLRequest=new URLRequest('http://www.yoursite.com/donate');
    navigateToURL(ur, '_blank');
}
```

This is, of course, the click event handler to the 'Donate' button